# What power supply for this PC?

Tags: power-supply

I'm planning to build PC from following parts:

> Processor: Intel i5-6500
>
> Cooling: Corsair Hydro Series H55
>
> Graphics: Gigabyte GeForce GTX970 Gaming G1
>
> HDD: WD 1TB 64MB BLUE
>
> RAM: Crucial 8192MB 1600MHz CL11
>
> Motherboard: ASUS H170-PLUS D3
>
> Case: Fractal Design Define R5 Black Pearl

Now this almost exhausted by budget. I am looking for a durable power supply for this PC, that wouldn't make me go bankrupt. Bonus points if you can find it [on this site(in polish)](http://www.x-kom.pl/)

Comment: Do you have a specific budget in mind?

Comment: @Undo As I said, I almost exhausted my budget, so I would be most satisfied if it was relatively cheap but good, but if I were to name the price, then not more than 300zł(which is ~75$) - and preferably less then that.

Comment: So, to clarify, you wish to use this PSU for a gaming build (high peak loads for short times), for a relatively long duration (5+ years) and wish to spend less than 300zł (PLN) and ooptimally around 200zł. Is efficency or cable management a priority?

Comment: @MatthewRock I can read and write in polish, so this site is not a problem. However, Do you have a specific need of watts? (I've never physically built a pc before [though I wish I could] so I don't really know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using eXtreme Outer Vision's eXtreme Power Supply calculator, the power consumption of your build comes to about 390 W. With some overclocking, this becomes 470 W. Any decent 500 - 550 W PSU should handle the load fine for several years with no problems, even if you do overclock a bit later.

I personally won't recommend the Corsair VS series, as it uses poor quality capacitors. Here are my recommendations from the site you posted.

**[Antec 550W VPF550 EC](http://www.x-kom.pl/p/222686-zasilacz-komputerowy-antec-550w-vpf550-ec.html)**

The Antec VPF line is a relatively new series manufactured by Delta Electronics. It has Japanese capacitors and a 24 month warranty. Currently it is priced at 249 zł. Non modular, but that isn't much of a problem for lower capacity PSUs, it also has 80 + Bronze certification.

**[XFX Core TS 550W](http://www.x-kom.pl/p/250429-zasilacz-komputerowy-xfx-core-ts-550w.html)**

The XFX TS series is a budget series manufactured by Seasonic (one of the best manufacturers of PSUs out there). It also has Japanese capacitors and a 60 month warranty (that's right, 5 years). It's one of my favorite recommendations: High quality at a relatively low price. Again, has 80+ Bronze certification and is non modular.

I took some time to shop around on some other Polish sites (which was a breeze as soon as I figured out what the word for Power Supply was), and I found the TS selling slightly cheaper at [komputronik.pl](http://www.komputronik.pl/product/120162/Sprzet_komputerowy_/Podzespoly/XFX_Core_550W_120mm_80_SLI_PSU.html). Overall, I think both PSUs will fit your needs, and it is up to you to choose the one you like better. Good luck.

Comment: If newegg includes shipping costs in their price, the [Seasonic S12II](http://www.newegg.com/global/pl/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817151094) might also be an option.

Comment: I went with XFX Core TS. 5 years warranty looks nice; I think I'll be happy with the purchase.

Answer (score 3):

I've taken a look at the website and here are my final two options:

1. [Thermaltak 450w](http://www.x-kom.pl/p/226049-zasilacz-komputerowy-thermaltake-450w-tr2-120mm-oem.html) 
   Modular? No. (-)
   Cost? 159 zł. (+)
   Size/Length? 120mm.
   Warranty? 24 months. (+)
2. [Corsair VS Series, 550w](http://www.x-kom.pl/p/206808-zasilacz-komputerowy-corsair-vs-series-550w-80plus-box.html) 
   Modular? No. (-)
   Cost? 215 zł. (+)
   Size/Length? 120mm.
   Warranty? 36 months. (++)

I would take the Corsair VS Series, as it has a better warranty and it has 100 more watts and is only 75 zł higher in price. Since you want a durable & long-lasting PSU, this seems to be it.

Comment: as the OP wants a "durable power supply for this PC" I would not opt for the Corsair VS Series because it uses [low quality capacitors](http://www.hardwareinsights.com/wp/corsair-vs450-review/4/) and is considered a [Tier 4 PSU](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-2547993/psu-tier-list.html). Very bad for this otherwise very good hardware.The Thermaltake one TR2 450W should be the better choise as it uses higher quality capacitors from japan and 450 Watt will be more than enough for this hardware.

Comment: I said, I have no previous experience so I didn't know.

Comment: yeah no problem just wanted to add that information :) no harm done